# Using Network Analyst in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I would like to open up a new settlement with fiberglass and i want to know how much route in meter I need to open up each house in this settlement.

For this purpose I will use the network analyst in ArcGIS.

The problem with this tool is that it always calculates the distance between the settlements entrance and each house.

The point is that there should be one route entering the main street in this settlement and from this main route there should be little routes to each house.

The main route should be only calcuated once and not for every house.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: I believe you should look at geometric networks, they might suit your needs better. What is the underlying data you traverse - street polylines?

Comment: Fiberglass? Do you mean Fiberoptic? If so, related questions include http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20533/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29867/ Which solver in Network Analyst are you using? As Alex suggests, a geometric network might be better suited.

Answer (score 2):

If you will work extensively with such type of analysis, you might consider looking at geometric networks, they might suit your needs better.

As a workaround, do the following:

1. After solving the Route, use the GP tool Copy Traversed Source Features. This will export your edges that were traversed.
2. In the Edges feature class, delete duplicates (they will have the same SourceOID value). Either use Delete Identical GP tool (Advanced license) or write a custom Python script / build a model (or just Dissolve on the SourceOID field).

[image]